# c++ output lua syntax error

Tags: c++, lua

I'm using `cocos2d-x`.

When my lua code has logic error,it will print traceback in `C++` (`VS2013`).
but if lua code has syntax error,it just print

```
'[LUA ERROR] load "path/file.lua", error: syntax error during pre-compilation'
```

But which line is error ?

Comment: Please provide your sorce code. Otherwise we will not be able to help you.

Comment: I want the output like this
[LUA-print] LUA ERROR:[string "a.lua"]:46: module 'b.lua' not found:
no field package.preload['b.lua'][string "b.lua"]:5595: ')' expected near 'print'
.......
.......

Comment: cocos2dx 3.9   AppDelegate.cpp

Comment: cocos2dx 3.9   AppDelegate.cpp
bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()
{
    ......
    LuaEngine::getInstance()->executeScriptFile("test.lua");
    return true;
}

test.lua (I make a syntax error like this)
print("abcabc"                      --  line 5595  maybe

when i run this program,it print '[LUA ERROR] load "test.lua", error: syntax error during pre-compilation'

I hope it told me which line is error please .......

Answer (score 0):

Most text editors will show syntax errors while in the editor by underlining it in red. This is usually enough to find the problem. Some even give a description of the problem when you hover over it.

Comment: I'd provide a more detailed answer but you've given is no code to review.

Comment: I'm designed to make some syntax error,i want to get syntax error detail in c++ output